# How do I migrate a Virtualbox image to an LXC container?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, lxc

Is there a way to migrate a Virtualbox image to a LXC containter environment?

I can easly extract a tar of the Virtualbox VM's file system. I'm kind of hoping there's a way to create an 'empty' container and then untar the virtualbox VM's file system into it.

I am completely new to LXC but if anyone can lay out the steps I'll lookup any details.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who might be wondering:

The following article covers booting a raw image as a container.
Perfect for my situation as we use raw images with virtualbox.

https://www.stgraber.org/2012/03/04/booting-an-ubuntu-12-04-virtual-machine-in-an-lxc-container/

Charlie101

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. And it would be a bonus if you include the steps to convert regular Virtualbox image to raw (as the question is about Virtualbox in general).

Comment: I only use raw images with Virtualbox because it makes it easier to mount, extract tars, or copy directly onto other devices like disk partitions and usb sticks. I didn't put this in my question because I didn't want to like relivant answers.